# Updated state doesn't force rerender

Tags: reactjs

I have this child Component which receives an ID as props and gets the rest of its data into its own state.

```
import React from 'react';

class ReactionBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      reactionClass: "content-box reactionBoxContainer hide",
      reaction_icons: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(e){
    this.setState({
      reactionClass: "content-box reactionBoxContainer hide showAnim"
    });
  }
  componentWillMount(e){
    var that = this;
    var reqObj = {
      request: "reaction list"
    };
    $.post( "/apicall", reqObj, function( data ) {
      that.setState({
        reaction_icons: data
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.reaction_icons.length);
    if(this.state.reaction_icons.length > 0){
      var SingleReaction = this.state.reaction_icons.map(function(reaction) {
        console.log("map");
        return (
          <li key={reaction.id}>
            <img src={reaction.url} width={reaction.width + "px"} alt={reaction.name} />
          </li>
        );
      });
    }
    return(
      <div>
       <ul>
        {this.state.reaction_icons.legnth > 0 ? SingleReaction : 'Loading...'}
       </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ReactionBox;
```

From my console logs I can tell, that the state gets updated as well as that the mapping function gets executed as many times as much elements get passed with the updated state.

Unfortunately this line : `{this.state.reaction_icons.legnth > 0 ? SingleReaction : 'Loading...'}` doesn't rerender or rerun. Even tho the updated state length is greater than 0 it still prints out "Loading..."

Comment: Your example says `legnth` not `length`. Is that typo in your actual code?

Comment: Also you can get rid of `that = this` if you use an arrow function for your `$.post` callback.

Comment: oh my god ... well yes it was a typo ^^